# How can i call "sendTaskSuccess" that return the token to a waiting state in stepfunction. not using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have an external service which is called by a state in aws step function, now from this external service i want to send "sendTaskSuccess" to the particular aws step machine. How can i do that. I know that we can call "sendSuccessToken" from lambda but want to know how to use "sendSuccessToken" without lambda.

Comment: Where is StateMachine ARN is used while sending "SendsuccessToken". Or if StateMachine ARN is not used why it is not used , how to know which step function to send token

Answer (score 1):

The state machine ARN is not used .The step in the state machine that await a callback have a taskToken which uniquely identifies a specific task and a specific execution of state machine.

The ideal way to do this would be :
**Step 1:**
Store the taskToken in a persistent storage before invoking the external service

```
export const lambdaHandler: ProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {

    const evt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event));
    const taskToken = evt['token'];
    
    const dbObject = 
    {
        SomeHelpfulInfo: 'set a suitable identifier',
        taskToken:taskToken
    };
    StoreTaskToken(dbObject);
    //call external service as per your logic
//

}
```

**Step 2:**
Read the taskToken from the persistent storage and invoke the step function task success

```
import { StepFunctions } from 'aws-sdk';

const stepfunctions = new StepFunctions();

const taskToken = GetTaskTokenFromDb(); //Have your implementation to get taskToken

const params = {
            output: '',
            taskToken: taskToken
        };
        
let result = await stepfunctions.sendTaskSuccess(params).promise();
console.log('State machine - callback completed..');
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi, I got the answer previously after reading some documentations, thanks for the long reply.